# JLabel not appearing on JPanel

Tags: java, swing

My `JLabel` with assigned picture wont show up for a game I am making. Here is the relevant code. The `JLabel` is added to the `JPanel` but it does not show up, the label has a location and responds to the key listener and moves as such but will not appear on screen.
game is a LayeredPane
players is a JPanel that the Player Models are supposed to be on
ply1 is the sample Sprite that moves around on the screen
the other 600 lines of code admit no discourse to the game layered pane or the players JPanel.

The issue is that the ply1 JLabel is not showing up on the JPanel yet it has a location on the panel but is not visible.

```
    public Game() throws IOException{
        game.setLayout(bord);
        JLabel cort = new JLabel();
        
        players.setLayout(null);
        
        
        cort.setSize(1366,768);
        cort.setIcon(court);
        game.add(cort,0);
        players.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        players.setOpaque(false);
        
        
        game.add(players,1);
        
        ply1.setLayout(null);
        ply1.setIcon(player1s);
        ply1.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        ply1.setVisible(true);
        players.add(ply1, bord.WEST);
        ply1.setLocation(x,y);
        
        game.repaint();
        players.setVisible(true);
        players.repaint();
        game.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                game.revalidate();
                game.requestFocus();
                System.out.println("pressed " + e.getKeyCode());
                int key = e.getKeyCode();
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                    frame.setContentPane(startMenu);
                    frame.revalidate();
                    frame.repaint();
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                        x = x+10;
                        
                        ply1.setLocation((int)ply1.getLocation().getX() + 10, (int)ply1.getLocation().getY());
                        ply1.setVisible(false);
                        ply1.setVisible(true);
                        ply1.revalidate();
                        
                        players.repaint();
                        players.revalidate();
                        System.out.println(ply1.getLocation());
                    
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm a little confused because it doesnt seem like this is valid Java code. Is `Game` your class? I assume `game` is a JFrame?

Comment: 1) In your description of the problem, you say "Panel" and you tag awt, but you say "JPanel" in your title. Swing and AWT are different. 2) In relation to (1) can you clarify some of your variables such as `players`, `game`, and `frame`? 3) Also, can you perhaps [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64720710/edit) and post/link a picture of your problem because currently, it isn't clear what exactly is happening?

Comment: @PranavAmarnath Yeah. Theres definitely something wrong going on here. I have some edits pending on the post to address some of the issues you mentioned, but for sure we need some clarification on stuff, especially when you consider `public Game() ` is not valid Java...

Comment: Your question is why doesn't the label show up on the panel. So why did you post code related to a KeyListener. The code is irrelevant. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and the the code. Don't use a transparent color. All you need is the setOpaque( false ). Components are visible by default. Invoking repaint() in a constructor does nothing.

Comment: @thetechnician94 I think the `public Game()` was the constructor method, but it was a little hard to tell due to the necessary refactoring of the code.

Comment: @PranavAmarnath Yeah. Could be I guess. I guess I'm just not used to doing *so much* in a constructor like that and was also expecting a class declaration.... Anyway, more work is required here before there's much we can do.

Comment: You're using a null LayoutManager. LayoutManagers are there for the convenience of the programmers. Not using them causes problems like the one you're experiencing.

Comment: I cut the code down to a minimal amount as the actual program is massive this is the only code that references the JLabel ply1, JPanel players, and JLayeredContentPane game. The Panel processes the location of the label but the sprite does not show up. the console puts out the constant location of the JLabel relative to the screen. The public Game() is a constructor part of a larger class, the KeyListener is nessecary because it has influence on the JPanel and JLabel

Comment: You `ply1.setLayout(null);` which makes absolutely no sense for a JLabel. You call `players.add(ply1, bord.WEST);` which implies you have a border layout, but you also call `players.setLayout(null);` So you have a null layout!? You also set `players` background color, but make if non-opaque. Why would you do that? You should create a minimal example with a JLabel, JLayeredPane and JFrame. It looks like you have a lot of code that could just be deleted. There is a [layered pane tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

The Content Pane is layered incorrectly, the background is layered over top of the characters. Content panes count starting at the top layer of 0 every number in further behind it.